# NGINX reverse proxy changing variable

Tags: nginx

We are trying to use NGINX as a reverse proxy to filter out URL requests.  Basically if you don't type the correct URL, you don't get access.

Here is my server site config:

```
server {

    listen 192.168.1.63:443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.key;

    server_name domain.test.com;

    set $upstream 192.168.1.10;

    location ~* /(domain1|domain2|domain3|domain4|%7FVIC) {
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_pass http://$upstream;
       }
}
```

All works great, except for the `%7FVIC`.   The application we are trying to protect, the clients need to access a variable/something at the root of the site.  So the url is: `https://domain.test.com/%7FVIC01663918`

When I watch the logs, it seems that NGINX is intercepting the variable and rewriting it.  Here is the snippet from the error logs:

```
2018/06/18 14:57:30 [error] 11647#11647: *16 open() "/usr/share/nginx/htmlVIC01663918" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: test.domain.com, request: "POST /%7FVIC01663918 HTTP/1.1", host: "test.domain.com", referrer: "https://test/domain.com/domain1/"
```

It looks like it is changing the `%7FVIC` to `/htmlVIC01663918`

So how do we get NGINX to bypass just that variable or ignore and stop changing it?

Answer (score 0):

The `%7F` is a URL encoded representation of a 7Fh character code. `nginx` will decode it before processing the request. You can insert a 7Fh character into your regular expression `location` statement, but you must use *regular expression* syntax rather than URL syntax (e.g. `\x7F`).

For example:

```
location ~* /(domain1|domain2|domain3|domain4|\x7FVIC) { ... }
```